# Scope of the jquery ajax success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

if I have

```
function AjaxRequest(){
    var testvar = 0;
    for(i=0;i<d.length;i++){
        $.ajax({
            success: function(a){
                testvar++;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Will testvar increase on success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; the variable is captured by the function's closure.
Closures keep variables alive so that nested functions can still use them later.

Note that the `success` callbacks only run some time after the rest of your code finishes (AJAX is asynchronous).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. It's similar to this:

```
function() {
   var self = this;
    this.a = function(){
        self.something;
    }
}
```