# jScrollPane synchronicity

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm having a synchronicity problem with jScrollPane.
I'm updating a div content via Ajax, when this div is updated i have to reinitialize jScrollPane. When the html code is too large, the jScrollPane() call seems to use just a part of the content i'm updating, and some elements stays out of the scrollPane. If i put the jScrollPane() call inside a setTimeout with a second, it works, but i know that is not a good way to solve this.
Sorry my bad english.

That's the code:

```
success : function(HTMLcode){ 
    $("#div_inside").empty().html(HTMLcode); 
    $('#pane').jScrollPane(); 
    //SET SCROLL POSITION 
    $('#pane')[0].scrollTo(panetop); 
}
```

Comment: Are you using the [`success` callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7326933/901048) in your AJAX call? Please provide more of your code.

Comment: Yes, that portion of code is in the success callback of the ajax call.
The problem is that the jScrollPane() is called before the html() function ends (its my opinion), the code inside the div is not fully rendered.  
This is the code in the success callback:
  
    `success : function(HTMLcode){  
        $("#div_inside").empty().html(HTMLcode);
        $('#pane').jScrollPane();
        //SET SCROLL POSITION
        $('#pane')[0].scrollTo(panetop);
    }`

Comment: Are you loading HTML code with images?

Comment: Yes, te response of the ajax call is an html list with divs, images, etc.  
If this list have few elements (10) it's ok, the problem appears when this list is longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem recently -- turned out that once the HTML had loaded, the external images in that HTML hadn't. So: HTML loads, then jScrollpane resizes, and THEN the images load and change the length of the HTML again.

The weak solution is to trigger jScrollpane with a `setTimeout`, as you have.

The good solution is to go through your HTML that's being loaded and assign width and height attributes to EVERY image tag. That way, it will be the correct length even before the images load.

If you can't edit that loaded HTML, though, then the `setTimeout` is probably your simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've added the size in the img tags and it's working properly now

Comment: I also had a similar problem and couldn't figure out what was causing the issue. Added HTML size dimensions and it worked like a charm!